# Xcode - device console logs for past session

Tags: iphone, xcode, eaaccessory

This issue has been bugging me a lot lately. I am working on an app that connects with external accessories and sends the data to server. I need to look at the console logs to make sure data being sent is correct however i can not attach the device to mac when I accessory is connected. How can I see console logs after I am done using the app?

Comment: I've asked an engineer at Infinite Peripherals about this. They couldn't provide a solution.